# QLPreviewController -- how to pause video play programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, qlpreviewcontroller

I have an app with a QLPreviewController and need to know how to pause video play programmatically. I haven't seen anything in QLPreviewController or QLPreviewItem that would allow me to do that.

Comment: You would have to use the `AppDelegate`. In there, you could either grab a hold of your QLVC, or you could also send a notification and setup the QLVC to observe that notification and pause (and play) when it fires.

Comment: i know how to hook into the AppDelegate notifications. the issue is how to actually pause the video from playing. i can't find any method I could call on QLPreviewController or QLPreviewItem to control video play.

Comment: Oh then you should rephrase your question, because if you just need to find a way to pause the video, it doesn't have to do anything with the app entering background. Am I getting you right?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth thank you, you're right. i edited my question.